# Does C# have a way of making this statement more compact?

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code like

```
return x != null ? new Something() { Foo = x.Something, Bar = x.SomethingElse } : null;
```

I can't use the null propagating operator here because it's the opposite of what I want (It would have me define what to return if `x` is `null`, not if `x` isn't `null`). Yet I don't like what I have.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You could create an extension method off of whatever x is, which would allow you to then do:

```
return x?.toSomething();
```

Comment: You don't even need to use `?.` just make your extension method robust enough to support a null being passed in for the `this` parameter. and you can do `x.toSomething();`

Answer (score 1):

More compact than this using regular syntax ***no***.

BTW, you can implement an extension method:

```
return x.MapIfNotNull(o => new Something { Foo = o.Something, Bar = o.SomethingElse });
```

Where the extension method would look as follows:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
     public static T MapIfNotNull<T, TReturn>(this T some, Func<T, TReturn> map)
            where T : class
     {
          Contract.Requires(map != null);

          return some != null ? map(some) : null;
     }
}
```

You can even go beyond and simplify the instantiation:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
     public static T MapIfNotNull<T, TReturn>(this T source, Func<T, TReturn, TReturn> map)
            where TReturn : class, new()
     {
          Contract.Requires(map != null);

          if(source == null)
             return;

          TReturn target = map(source, new TReturn());

          return target;
     }
}
```

...and use it as follows:

```
return x.MapIfNotNull<A, B>((s, t) => { t.Foo = s.Something; t.Bar = s.SomethingElse; });
```

Or you can even use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to simplify it even more:

```
return mapper.Map<A, B>(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not shorter when you consider number of characters, but it *is* shorter in width so still more likely to fit on your screen, and very readable:

Simply split it into two statements. Be only just clever enough to avoid trying to be too clever.

```
if (x == null) return null;
return new Something { Foo = x.Something, Bar = x.SomethingElse };
```